# TOPOJSON showing up differently between MAPSHAPER and PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, shapefile, qgis, topojson, mapshaper

I've created a Map with MAP QGIS that I was able to import in Mapshaper and it looks exactly as I want it. However, when I select it as custom shape map in Power Bi it doesn't show as it was supposed. The map I created is just a map of Canada that I added a rectangle polygon for a specific region.

I was able to create a single layer with everything I want in MAP QGIS saved as Shapefile. Using this file I've imported in Mapshaper to create a TOPOJSON. Once I exported the TOPOJSON, I've selected this file in Power Bi as Custom Shape map. However the shape map in Power Bi doesn't include the added rectangle polygon. I tried importing the TOPOJSON in Mapshaper and I could see the rectangle. I'm not sure if it's an attribute.